# How Can I Use Data For Apps Blocked on Wi-Fi Networks?

Tags: wi-fi

All questions that are similar to this one appeared to be asking the opposite of what I want.

At my job certain applications do not work when connected to the associate wi-fi network. If I turn off Wi-Fi and use data only then the applications work.

Is there a way to make it so that these 'blocked' applications will use data while on the associate network, but then go back to using Wi-Fi when the phone is connected to my home Wi-Fi?

Phone is Moto Z Force (XT1650) with Android 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to keep data enabled while being on Wi-Fi, and redirect application UID using netfilter, which require root to alter it's settings.